# Pythagoras: Get b when only a and angle α are given

Tags: geometry, angle

Given the Pythagoras Theorem: **a² + b² = c²**

Is there a way to get the value of **b** when we only have a value for **a** and the angle **α**?

To be frank, I have no clue about that, what I want isn't the angle of **β** but the length of **b** (Opposite).

[image]

Comment: Since you know there is a right-angle, in fact you know all the angles and a side.

Comment: The adjacent is given

Comment: The Pythagoras Theorem gives the relation between the sides of a right triangle. It knows nothing about angles (apart from the right angle), so it's not particularly relevant here.

Comment: Usually, the "adjacent" side is the one next to the angle of interest, while $\alpha$ is the angle opposite $a$.

Comment: (In this case, the adjacent is $a$, as it says in the picture)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$a = b\tan\theta$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle opposite to $a$

From this:

$$b = \frac{a}{\tan\theta}$$

Comment: The opposite angle from α!! ... and no clue about the `tan()`function either. thx alot.

Comment: Does this mean you understand the problem now, or does it mean that you don't know the $\tan$-function?

Answer (score 1):

Pythagoras Theorem is a theorem about right-angle triangles so if we know one of the angles (except $90^{\circ}$, which is not the case in here), then we know all of the angles and knowing one of the sides of the triangle is enough for finding other two.